# why isn't the pointer incrementing

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

Being new to c++ I've been practicing with questions. One program I wrote includes the use of structs and arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void){
struct CandyBar{
    char brandName[200];
    float weight;
    int calories;
};

CandyBar snacks[3] = {
    {"Cadbury's Flake",23.5,49},
    {"Cadbury's Wispa",49.3,29},
    {"Cadbury's Picnic",57.8,49},
};

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    cout << "Brand Name: " << snacks[i].brandName << endl;
    cout << "Weight: " << snacks[i].weight << endl;
    cout << "Calories: " << snacks[i].calories << endl;
    snacks++;
}

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

The above program fails becuase of the "snacks++", but I can't understand why. As I understand arrays they are made of two parts the pointer ("snacks") and the object ([]), so shouldn't the "snacks++" work as I am incrementing the pointer?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Arrays are not made up of a pointer and an object. And why do you want to change the value of `snacks`? In your own words, you would be changing the array!

Comment: What does it mean to add one to the value of an array and store the result in the array?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just remove the `snacks++;`
you are already using the variable `i` as a index in the array.

if you do want to use a pointer arithmetics:
a. you should define a pointer to the start of the array and work with it rather then work with the array.
b. you should use a pointer instead of the array with index `i` when accessing the data.

```
struct CandyBar* ptr = snacks;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    cout << "Brand Name: " << ptr->brandName << endl;
    cout << "Weight: " << ptr->weight << endl;
    cout << "Calories: " << ptr->calories << endl;
    ptr++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`snacks` isn't a pointer. Its type is `CandyBar[3]` not `CandyBar*`. However, array convert to pointers really easy:

```
CandyBar* snackIterator = snacks;
```

(you should be clear what you are using pointers for: there are many uses which makes themsomewhat confusing).

Comment: If I take away the snacks[i] and the loop and change to snacks->weight that works so that tells me that snacks is a pointer, so I still don't understand why snacks++ throws an error?

Comment: @Dan no that doesn't tell you that `snacks` is a pointer, it tells you that pointer dereferencing syntax works on array variables, and that array variables are allowed to automatically cast to a pointer.   It might sound nitpicky, but there's actually a huge difference between arrays and pointers;  pointers are simple numeric objects just like int/char which store a numeric value (an address value), whereas arrays are larger "chunks" ("blocks") of memory which represent multiple objects.   Incrementing a pointer (a number) makes sense, but incrementing an array doesn't.

Comment: @Dan: just because you can use an array in some aspects like a pointer doesn't mean that it is a pointer. You can also use a pointer like an array in some aspects (i.e. the subscript operator works on pointers, too) but they are no arrays. Entities in programming each have some interface and although the interfaces may have some overlap they are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

While it's possible to use an array as a pointer, it is not a pointer in the compiler. Therefore you can not change the `snacks` variable. If you were allowed to change the "pointer", it would no longer "point" to the beginning of the array after the loop, but at the entry beyond the array which is uninitialized memory.

Also, you don't need to change the `snacks` variable, `snacks[i]` already fetches the correct values for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the value of `snacks`.
You should use a pointer instead of `snacks`.

And you won't need to increase the pointer while you are increasing `i` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`snakes` starts off as the first item in the list. You use `snacks[[i]` to index that list. But you also shift the goal post to the first item in the list with `snacks[++` Hence you use the next item in the array as the stareting point. i.e. there is your problem. Do one or the other.

Comment: I just added wanted to test whether my assumption about this array pointer is correct so I just added it in the loop. If I take away the snacks[i] and the loop and change to snacks->weight that works so that tells me that snacks is a pointer, so I still don't understand why snacks++ throws an error?

Comment: since snacks can't be changed. It's an array, `snacks` is the pointer to the first element of the array, interpret it like a shortform for `&snacks[0]`.

Comment: @ShinTakezou That's a very misleading statement - in the OP's example `snacks` is the array itself and **not** a pointer-to the first element.    Pointers are objects in their own right and occupy memory just like other numeric data types; when you declare an array, you are not creating a pointer, you're simply allocating a chunk of memory for that array.    The C FAQ explains in more detail here: http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html

Comment: @BenC Of course those words were an attempt at explaning it in the way the OP (I believed) could understand. If you *interpret* snacks as `&snacks[0]`, you come to get (I supposed) why `snacks++` gives error (since I think it is clear why `(&snacks[0])++` gives error). I wrote: *snacks can't be changed*. **It's an array** (though it's not totally correct to say so). — Nonetheless, `snacks` **is** a pointer, though it is not "stored" so you can't increment it, and it is exactly `&snacks[0]` in value. What you get with `&` has the same nature (not only because they are both pointers).